# Passing variable in multi project git pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, multi-project

YML of my trigger project:

```
trigger:
  variables:
    CODE_SHA: ${SHA}
  stage: test
  trigger:
    project: dummy
    branch: dump
    strategy: depend
```

YML of my triggered project:

```
build:docker3.7:
  stage: build
  retry: 2
  script:
    - echo $code_sha
```

Ideal behaviour: It should print ${SHA} from the trigger project in triggered project.

Present behaviour- no value is getting passed.

Comment: already seen [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#passing-cicd-variables-to-a-downstream-pipeline)?

Comment: Yes I saw it...

Comment: CODE_SHA ≠ code_sha

Comment: Yes i realized that. Thanks @JkbLskw